# funcion unicos excel valor 0

Tags: excel, funciones

me encuentro obteniendo de una tabla "NO DINAMICA" de una columna llamada Observaciones, hay celdas en la columna que están vacías, cosa que extraigo los datos únicos con la función y me devuelven los valores únicos pero a diferencia que hay un valor 0 siendo que en dicha columna no hay ninguna celda que tenga el valor de cero, habrá alguna solución a este problema?

Necesito que, al obtener los datos únicos con la función, en el que intento que no me arroje juntos los valores de las celdas un 0

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Gana tu primera medalla visitando el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula en la celda A9 es la que estás usando y te devuelve ceros en las celdas en blanco:

```
=UNICOS(A1:A6)
```

La fórmula en la celda B9 es lo que quieres, ignorar las celdas en blanco. Combina la función anterior con un FILTRAR:

```
=UNICOS(FILTRAR(B1:B6;B1:B6<>""))
```

> [Función
> FILTRAR](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-filtrar-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

Comment: Oh que maravilla de respuesta, pude solucionar el problema en un instante, Gracias maestro Esei.